# Join two datasets based on latitude and distance

Tags: r, merge, geo, full-join

I have two datasets that I am trying to merge together based on the latitude. The latitudes do not exactly match so it has to be closest latitude by say 30km. When I try full join, the output data frame is sequential (i.e., it spits out df then df2 rather than merging/joining them. Is there a way I can merge these two data frames into one based on how close they are in latitude?

```
Var1 <- c(1, 4, 6, 2, 8, 9, 2, 4, 5, 4)
Var2 <- c(1.9, 2.4, 3.7, 7.3, 2.4, 4.8, 9, 2.3, 9, 1.7)
Lat <- c(57.33, 58.21, 58.93, 59.23, 59.87, 60.29, 60.99, 61.5, 61.8, 62.5)
Lon <- c(131, 131, 131, 130.9, 130.99, 130.5, 131, 131, 131.2, 131)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Var1, Var2, Lat, Lon))

Var1 <- c(4, 3, 6, 8, 1, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8)
Var2 <- c(6.2, 3, 5.6, 5.1, 9.0, 2.4, 4.9, 8.2, 3.1, 6.2)
Lat <- c(57.15, 58.3, 59.0, 59.4, 60.0, 60.1, 61.0, 61.6, 62, 62.7)
Lon <- c(131, 131, 131, 130.9, 130.99, 130.5, 131, 131, 131.2, 131)

df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Var1, Var2, Lat, Lon))

Vic = df%>%
  full_join(df2, by = c("Lat" = "Lat"))
```

I also tried geo_join but I get an error

```
merged.dfs <- geo_join(df, df2, by = NULL, method = "haversine", mode = "left", max_dist = 1) 

Joining by: c("Var1", "Var2", "Lat", "Lon")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
Trying to join on Var1, Var2, Lat, Lon; geo_join needs exactly   two columns (latitude and longitude)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fuzzyjoin` package and the `geo_join` function is definitely the way to go.
You were close with your try, you just need to set up some parameters as the error mentioned.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
Var1 <- c(1, 4, 6, 2, 8, 9, 2, 4, 5, 4)
Var2 <- c(1.9, 2.4, 3.7, 7.3, 2.4, 4.8, 9, 2.3, 9, 1.7)
Lat <- c(57.33, 58.21, 58.93, 59.23, 59.87, 60.29, 60.99, 61.5, 61.8, 62.5)
Lon <- c(131, 131, 131, 130.9, 130.99, 130.5, 131, 131, 131.2, 131)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Var1, Var2, Lat, Lon))

Var1 <- c(4, 3, 6, 8, 1, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8)
Var2 <- c(6.2, 3, 5.6, 5.1, 9.0, 2.4, 4.9, 8.2, 3.1, 6.2)
Lat <- c(57.15, 58.3, 59.0, 59.4, 60.0, 60.1, 61.0, 61.6, 62, 62.7)
Lon <- c(131, 131, 131, 130.9, 130.99, 130.5, 131, 131, 131.2, 131)

df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Var1, Var2, Lat, Lon))

Vic <-  df%>%
  geo_join(df2, by = c("Lat" = "Lat", "Lon" = "Lon"), method = "haversine", mode = "left", max_dist = 30, unit = "km" )
```

Look into [this documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/fuzzyjoin/html/geo_join.html) if needed

Comment: Glad I could help, please remember that the fuzzyjoin is joining different values on latitude and longitude ! So you need to control your data if you want to join only on  the exact same longitude but on a close enough latitude

Comment: I ran into a problem. I did a linear interpolation on my 2 df from 0 to 4000 m in depth in 1 m intervals (so I have a large df). When I run the geo_join before interp, it works but after interp, I get an error: Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `indices = seq_len(number_y_rows)`.
ℹ In group 1: `STATION = 33`.
Caused by error:
! `indices` must be size 2578 or 1, not 111888. 
I thought this could be the NA's so I removed the NA's and the only difference was the size reduced but I get the same error `indices` must be size 2578 or 1, not 105844. Am I missing something?

Comment: It feels like you will need to post a new question, as I'm not familiar with what comes out of a linear interpolation